# Pthreads: memory getting corrupted

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a pthread program where  thread function accesses the information updated by the main. I am using a mutex to ensure synchronization, but I'm still observing a memory corruption:

1. Main thread  acquires lock and shall update the global data (via print debugs ensured that the data updated properly). Releases lock
2. thread will acquire lock and  access the global data`.` Here the data is corrupted.

I have the code snippet below. I am not sure if I have missed out something. Please provide your suggestions.

```
/* Global info*/
struct ThreadParams {
    struct ofconn *ofconn;
    const struct ofp_header *request;
};

#define NTHREADS      1
pthread_mutex_t     mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
struct ThreadParams threadParams;

enum ercode
handle_request(struct conn *conn, const struct header *request)
{
    int rc;
    printf("\n%s in!!",__func__);

    threadParams.conn = conn;
    threadParams.request = request;
    printf("\n\t%s: Request type %d", __func__,threadParams.request->type);

    printf("\n\t%s: Unlocking Mutex!!",__func__);
    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    checkResults("pthread_mutex_unlock()\n", rc);

    printf("\n\t%s: Completed\n",__func__);
    return 0;
}


void *thread_func()
{
    int rc;
    enum ercode error;

    printf("\n%s In!!",__func__);

    printf("\n%s: Locking Mutex!!\n",__func__);
    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    checkResults("pthread_mutex_lock()\n", rc);


    printf("\n%s:Received Lock with  Request type %d",
      __func__, threadParams.request->type); // data is corrupted here

    struct util_request fsr;
    error = _decode__request(&fsr, threadParams.request);
    if (error) {
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n\t%s: UnLocking Mutex!!",__func__);
    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    checkResults("pthread_mutex_lock()\n", rc);
    return NULL;
}


int main(void)
{
    int rc=0, i;
    pthread_t threadid[NTHREADS];


    printf("\n%s: Locking Mutex!!\n",__func__);
    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    checkResults("pthread_mutex_lock()\n", rc);

    for(i=0; i<NTHREADS; ++i) {
        rc = pthread_create(&threadid[i], NULL, thread_func, NULL);
        checkResults("pthread_create()\n", rc);
    }
    sleep(5);

    printf("\nCalling hanlde__request function\n");
    handle_request(ofconn, request);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fyi ,your `thread_func` isn't [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html) compliant. It should be `void * thread_func(void*);`, and you should use that param for passing thread-specific data from the creator. That's the first thing i would fix. Beyond that, this code can't possibly compile, much less produce the problems you're experiencing, *for **us***. Without a [minimum,**complete**, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces your problem, the very best you're apt to get are wild guesses.

Comment: `handle_request` unlocks the mutex but never locks it.  That seems pretty dangerous to me.  You didn't show the code for `_decode__request`.  Is that important?  Maybe you should show your output, and indicate where you are observing corruption.

Comment: @paddy: The `handle_request()` function is called by the main thread while it has the mutex locked.  It is not unreasonable, therefore, for `handle_request()` to simply unlock the mutex.  (This isn't the same as saying that `handle_request()` is bug free; it simply says that unlocking the mutex (once) is safe since it is locked when the function is entered.)

Comment: Is a `struct ofp_header` and a `struct header` the same type?  If so, how do you do it?  If not, you should be getting complaints from your compiler at `threadParams.request = request` which assigns a `struct header *` to a `struct ofp_header *`.  If your code does not compile squeaky clean (no warnings under high warning levels — like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`) then you shouldn't even attempt to run it.  You should fix the compilation errors.

Comment: It would be better if the lock and unlock were in the same routine.  Then you don't have to worry about unlocks without matching locks or locks that are never freed.

Comment: Don't printf with newlines at the start; always place the newline at the end of what's to output so it works in line buffered mode.